# Is there a way to regenerate link_to_add_association (specifically data-association-insertion-template)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

Built a very basic rails app to manipulate nested attributes using cocoon and the add and remove links work great.  However, it wasn't too long until I wanted to alter the underlying content of what was inserted, say in response to another field changing the list of option values in an included select tag.  It appears that the contents to be added are contained in an 'a' tag data element (data-association-insertion-template).  I can quite easily change the select options for all included lines via jQuery but changing the behavior of the link_to_add_association is beyond me.

Here are snippets of my example:

_form.html.erb

```
  <div>
    <strong>Entries:</strong>
    <div id="entries" style="border: thin solid">
      <%= f.fields_for :entries do |oi| %>
        <%= render "entry_fields", f: oi %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Entry', f, :entries, {id: 'cocoon-add-entry'} %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

_entry_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :item_id %>
  <%= f.select :item_id, @items.collect {|i| [i.style, i.id]}, {include_blank: true}, {selected: :item_id, multiple: false} %>

  <%= f.label :decoration_id, 'Decoration' %>
  <%= f.select :decoration_id, @decorations.collect { |d| [ d.name, d.id ] }, {include_blank: true}, {selected: :decoration_id, multiple: false, class: 'decoration'} %>

  <%= f.label :color %>
  <%= f.text_field :color %>

  <%= f.label :size_id %>
  <%= f.select :size_id, @sizes.collect { |s| [ s.name, s.id ] }, {include_blank: true}, {selected: :size_id, multiple: false} %>

  <%= f.label :number %>
  <%= f.number_field :number, value: 1, min: 1 %>

  <%= f.check_box :_destroy, hidden: true %>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Entry", f %>
</div>
```

orders.coffee

```
ready = ->
  $('.customer').change ->
    $.ajax
      url: '/orders/change_customer'
      data: { customer_id : @value }

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

order_controller.rb

```
  def change_customer
    @decorations = Decoration.joins(:logo).where('logos.customer_id = ?', params[:customer_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

change_customer.js.erb

```
// update all existing entry decorations with new customer driven options
<% new_decor = options_from_collection_for_select(@decorations, :id, :name) %>
var new_decor_options = "<option value='' selected='selected'></option>" + "<%=j new_decor %>";
$('.decoration').html(new_decor_options);

// now need to change $('#cocoon-add-entry').attr('data-association-insertion-template, ???);
// or regenerate link entirely - but don't have required data to do so here (form builder from original)
```

I have tried to manipulate the template data string directly via js str.replace but that is one ugly regular expression because of the unescapeHTML and htmlsafe operations done to make it an attribute in the first place.  And, that approach doesn't smell good to me.  I have been slowly working through the cocoon view_helpers and javascript but nothing seems to fit or I don't seem to have the right methods/data values to build a replacement link.  Suggestions?

BTW, kudos for cocoon gem.

Comment: Check out the callback which allows to manipulate the to be inserted (or inserted html) before or after inserting it. Check: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items

Comment: Thank you for the direction - I did skim that article. There is unfortunately one point I don't quite get though.  It happens to fall in the 'do something here' reference I believe. What I am trying to do is provide a new set of collection options for the add association link.  I send a request back to the server to get them and then want to either rebuild the link (but don't have the original FormBuilder to use in a call to link_to_add_association) or change this one portion of the insertion template in the existing html.  In the example, how and where would this change be enacted?

Comment: A callback allows to manipulate the to-be-inserted html using javascript, like change the list of available options. This would be a lot cleaner imho than what you propose now. Also, aside: when the customer changes (which is not in the form?) should not all dropdowns be changed? Or only new ones?

Comment: Thanks again.  The point about updating all dropdowns is correct and this is in fact done to all of the decoration class selects in the change_customer.js.erb. (Customer field is just not shown in the form snippet above).  In truth, I could change any of the option lists that vary by other field info changes if needed using this same mechanism.  The issue I have is getting the changes necessary from the database to populate the new option list which is done now via ajax call but not sure how the callback would be used in my coffeescript without waiting for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of gnashing of teeth, I have cobbled together a potential solution.  I haven't decided if I will let this go into production yet because of the limitations but thanks to combining several different SO questions and answers, the following works:

change_customer.js.erb

```
// update all existing entry decorations with new customer driven options
<% new_decor = options_from_collection_for_select(@decorations, :id, :name) %>
var new_decor_options = "<option value='' selected='selected'></option>" + "<%=j new_decor %>";
$('.decoration').html(new_decor_options);

// update the Add Entry link to capture new decorations set.
// Note use of ugly hack to recreate 'similar' form.
// Also note that this will only work for new order; will have to revise for edit.
'<%= form_for(Order.new) do |ff| %>'
$('#cocoon-add-entry').replaceWith("<%=j render partial: 'add_entry_link', locals: {f: ff} %>");
'<% end %>'
```

_add_entry_link.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add Entry', f, :entries, {id: 'cocoon-add-entry', data: {'association-insertion-method' => 'after'}} %>
```